# How to trim file segment length, so when written as new filepath is not longer than 255 chars for each segement

Tags: java, string

My Java code generates a new path name for an existing file, as part of this, I have to ensure each path segment is no longer than 255 characters because this is illegal for most operating systems.

```java
// No path component can be longer than 255 chars
String[] pathComponents = splitPath(newPath);
for(int i=0;i<pathComponents.length - 1;i++) {
    if (pathComponents[i]. length() > MAX_FILELENGTH) {
        String shortened = pathComponents[i].substring(0, MAX_FILELENGTH - 1);
        shortened = shortened.trim();
        sb.append(shortened).append(File.separator);
    }
    else {
        sb.append(pathComponents[i]).append(File.separator);
    }
}
```

This works fine most of the time, but it doesn't work if there are less than 255 Unicode characters but when the Unicode characters are written to the filesystem, some require more than one byte and therefore end up with more than 255 bytes, which isn't caught by test.

I can count bytes instead of characters with

```java
if(pathComponents[i].getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length > MAX_FILELENGTH)
```

I cannot work out a nice way to trim by just the right amount of characters.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, 255 characters are sometimes 255 bytes but sometimes they are longer. This simple test shows that:

```java
String a = "a";
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println((int)a.charAt(0));  
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
// a
// 97
// [97]


String aa = "ä";
System.out.println(aa);
System.out.println((int)aa.charAt(0));    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aa.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
// ä
// 228
// [-61, -92]
```

As you can see, the `ä` letter is part of 0-255 space (8 bytes) but it is represented by array with length = 2

What would I do? From question, I see that you generate the string, and in this new-path generator, I would create chars only in ASCII space (0-127). Then, you will be sure that generated string has one character as one byte, and `string.length()` will be the same as `getBytes().length`

The following code snippet shows that at 127th value everything is one byte long, and afterwards it is two byte long array. And you can also use that rule to shorten the string.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    char c = (char)i;
    String s = String.valueOf(c);
    System.out.println(i + "-> " + s + " ->" + Arrays.toString(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
}

// ...
// ...
// 125-> } ->[125]
// 126-> ~ ->[126]
// 127->  ->[127]
// 128->  ->[-62, -128]
// 129->  ->[-62, -127]
// 130->  ->[-62, -126]
```

Comment: thx but I need to be able to support full unicode range not limit it to ascii space.

Comment: do you need unicode utf-8 or also utf-16 or more bytes?

Comment: I need to be able to write whatever characters are in string as part of filename whilst accounting for the fact that there is a limit of 255 bytes allowed, and therefore if more than 255 bytes need to truncate String so that when written will only require 255 bytes

Comment: @PaulTaylor The length in bytes depends on the actual character set used by the underlying file system.

Comment: okay lets assume UTF-8, usually UTF-8

Comment: @PaulTaylor It is not, for example NTFS (Windows) uses UTF-16, which means that - following your rules - you could use *at most* 127 characters, shorter if you have filenames with surrogate pairs.

Comment: Okay, but fine lets assume we know the underlying filesystem for a particular charset how do we adjust the string accordingly

Comment: @MarkRotteveel are you saying that NTFS only allows 127 chars in each file segment (since each char uses two bytes), or that NTFS actually supports 255 chars, 510 bytes if using UTF-16 (and have no Unicode char that requires surrogate pairs)

Comment: @PaulTaylor No, I'm saying _"following your rules"_. You have specified the requirement that it cannot exceed more that 255 bytes, so given NTFS uses UTF-16, following your rules, you would need to restrict it to 127 characters, irrespective of the actual limitations of NTFS itself (255 characters UTF-16 per path component, and - depending on Windows version and API used - 260 characters for the entire path).

Comment: Oh, okay so NTFS works with characters at underlying level so I dont need it for that will have to add check, linux filesystems usually seem to use UTf8  but restriction seem to based on byte length, is FAT bytes as well ?

Comment: Its confusing because linux fs uses UTF-8 but doesnt mean you can have 255 UTF-8 characters does it